# Get the latest occurence of object value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JSON array as follows

```
[{
    "x": {
        "id": "123"
    },
    "y": {
        "value": "123"
    }
}, {
    "x": {
        "id": "256"
    },
    "y": {
        "value": "256"
    }
}, {
    "y": {
        "value": "789"
    }
}]
```

How do i get the latest `id` value of object `x` and a array with all values of object `y`. So the output should be `256` & `[123, 256, 789]`

Comment: The json portion is irrelevant. You DECODE the json to a native data structure, and then your question becomes "how do I get last item of array in language X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the value and check for a given `id` and use it as last  value for `x`.

```js
var data = [{ x: { id: "123" }, y: { value: "123" } }, { x: { id: "256" }, y: { value: "256" } }, { y: { value: "789" } }],
    lastX,
    allY = data.map(function (a) {
        if (a.x && 'id' in a.x) {
            lastX = a.x.id;
        }
        return a.y.value;
    });

console.log(lastX);
console.log(allY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good answers here but I thought I'd chuck out a couple of one liners using lodash:

```
var lastX = _.get(_.findLast(data, 'x'), 'x.id');

var yvalues = _.map(data, 'y.value');
```

Comment: This looks even simpler with lodash :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by:

```
var yArray = [];
var xValue = 0;
foreach(object o in youJsonArray){
   xValue = o.x.id
   yArray.push(o.y.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json=JSON.parse('[{'+
    '"x": {'+
        '"id": "123"'+
    '},'+
    '"y": {'+
        '"value": "123"'+
    '}'+
'}, {'+
    '"x": {'+
        '"id": "256"'+
    '},'+
    '"y": {'+
        '"value": "256"'+
    '}'+
'}, {'+
    '"y": {'+
        '"value": "789"'+
    '}'+
'}]');
var y=[],
    x=0;
json.forEach(function(item,index){
  if(item.y)
  y.push(item.y.value);
  if(item.x)
  x=item.x.id;
});
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep this pretty short by using lodash:

```
_.map(arr, 'y.value');
// => ["123", "256", "789"]

_.get(
  _.findLast(arr, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.has, 'x'))),
  'x.id'
);
// => "256"
```

Note that both expressions use the string property path notation (`y.value` and `x.id`). This simple ability removes so much code that we would otherwise have to write for ourselves. The `unary()`, `partialRight()`, and `has()` functions are used to compose a `findLast()` iteratee function.